# Signal R persistent connection on phonegap apps (android and ios)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, signalr, signalr.client

I am using SignalR persistent connection for smooth communication between my client and server. All the web communications work really fine.

Now I am trying to do the same with my PhoneGap apps. It doesn't work. Is there any reason?

Here is my code

```
StartEvents = function () {

connection = $.connection(connectionString);
connection.logging = true;

connection.received(function (result) {

    for (i = 0; i < result.events.length; ++i) {

    }
});

connection.start().done(function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
};
```

It does log out connected at the start when the app is connected the first time. But then as events keep happening nothing is pushed from the server.

Server code is this

```
public class ApiConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        StartBroadcast(connectionId);
        return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
     }
}

private void StartBroadcast(string connectionId)
    {
        var timerCall = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        _subscription = timerCall.Subscribe(async res =>
        {
            List<dynamic> result = pull();

            if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
                await Connection.Send(connectionId, new
                {
                    id = _newestId,
                    events = result
                });
        });
    }
```